# CSS check for screen resolution

Tags: css, screen-resolution

Is there a reliable way to check for screen resolution using CSS?  I say reliable as I have been using the min-resolution media query which appeared to be working when my site was used on my desktop PC.  However, when used with a tablet (specifically a Windows Surface Pro 2) the screen DPI being reported was not what you would expect and my media query did not work.

Ultimately what I am trying to achieve is for larger buttons to be displayed when the screen DPI is over a certain value. The buttons look small otherwise. So I have CSS like this:

```
@media screen {
    .ui-top-pane {
        min-height: 135px;
        width: 100%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi), 
            (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    .ui-top-pane {
        min-height: 175px;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

But even though a Surface Pro 2 has a resolution of 1920 x 1080 and a screen size of 10", the DPI being reported is just 96.  So this would appear to be an unreliable way to detect this.  If this is the case, can anyone suggest a better way to do this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Related: [A pixel is not a pixel is not a pixel](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html)

Comment: Why not use css3: vw, vh for your button font sizes. This way it is allways relative to the viewport size.

Comment: can be done with javascript. CSS however it does very well